# Blue card employer change within six-seven months

Tags: germany, immigration, blue-card, employment

My zusatzblatt (green paper got along with blue card) has no employer name mentioned on it.(Location-Berlin)
I am planning to change or look for new opportunities , It is only 6 months now after I received the physical blue card.If I want to change the employer .
Heard that I need to notify the authorities about the change ,My question is do I just need to inform them with the new employer contract and start working already for the new company
Or should I need to wait till I get approval/reply from them and can only join the organisation after that

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.bamf.de/EN/Themen/MigrationAufenthalt/ZuwandererDrittstaaten/Migrathek/BlaueKarteEU/blauekarteeu-node.html a permit from the competent immigration authority is required for any change of job within the first two years of employment. The conditions for granting the Blue Card will then be re-examined. Approval is subject to the same preconditions as initial issuance, so that it is necessary, amongst other things, to prove the currently valid minimum gross salary again.

So you should wait for approval before changing employer.